# Track process at database level

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 2 tables called : PayPeriod and Contractor. I have one process, which will create the bill for contractors. Now I want to track that for one payperiod, for which contractors, bill is created. I want to track this because sometime there may be a case when for some of contractors, bill is not created.

How to track this at database level??? Need suggestion for table structure.

Answer (score 1):

You may create three table as given below to contain this information.

1. PayPeriod - Contains all bill periods
2. Contractor - Contains details for contractor
3. Bills - This table has foreign keys for Contractor and PayPeriod table and bill information.

Comment: I want to track that for which contractors, bill is created and for which period. Here in for one period, its creating bill for all contractors.So, I want to track that. And I don't want to save bill information.

Comment: @iDipa In Bills table you can have just bill number and foreign keys for given tables.